# Express two static files directory

Tags: node.js, express, static-files

My folder structure is as the following:

```
public
  css
  html
    main
      pllanet.html
server
  server.js
src
  img
  js
```

The `public` folder contains all HTML and CSS codes, and `src` folder contains img and js files. In server.js, I am using Express to indicated the static files directories as the following:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../public")));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../src")));
```

When I open pllanet.html, it doesn't seem like the app is picking up the second directory, since the images don't load. 
In the pllanet.html file, I have the css route as the following:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/main/pllanet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/main/home.css">
```

Could somebody help me, please? I am really stuck. Also, is it my folder structure a good practice?

Really appreciate your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can implemet `virtual path`

> To create a virtual path prefix (where the path does not actually exist in the file system) for files that are served by the express.static

`app.use('/static', express.static('public'))`

In your code, you could:

```
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../public")));
app.use('/resource', express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../src")));

// and link in html like
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/main/pllanet.css">
// img or js
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resource/img/someimage.jpg">
```

Comment: Hi naga, is there another way of doing it? I think I have to update all my refs of img src, etc. Thanks a lot

Comment: not that I can think of, since your refs are relative any change would probably involving changing paths.